# Laravel File Exception "Could not move the file"

Tags: php, image, file, laravel, upload

So I'm working on a basic file upload system that for the most part seems to be working. Most files go through perfectly and upload without a hitch, but for some reason, other files do not and I get the following error:

[image: could not move file]

This isn't a permissions error as it does work for some files - I don't believe it to be a filesize or filetype issue either.

My upload method is as follows:

```
$file = Input::file('photo');

$destinationPath    = 'user_img/';
$extension          = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
$rand               = str_random(12);
$filename           = 'usr_'.  Auth::user()->id . '_str=' . $rand . '_file='. Crypt::encrypt($file->getClientOriginalName()) .'.'. $extension;
$upload_success     = $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
```

I'm not finding any solution on the web, and I can't figure out why it's throwing this exception. Any ideas?

Comment: Already did. I stated that clearly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't want to count all characters in the filename in the screenshot, but there could be an issue with the length of your file name. [Wikipedia Filename - Length Restrictions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Length_restrictions)

Comment: Bingo! Thanks, got the same answer in the Laravel chatroom :)

Comment: Good catch, I also did not want to count the chars

Answer (score 2):

In my case, this was the issue: **using reserved characters in a file name.**

This is how i was getting the file name:

```
$photo_name = "User_".md5($user->id).'_'.date('Y-m-d H:i:s').".$ext";
```

This would mean that the eventual file name would have characters like `-`,`:` and `_`. On reading this Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Reserved_characters_and_words , i realised that the `:` (colon) is a reserved character and once i got rid of it (by amending the timestamp section to `date('Ymd_His')`, the error was gone and the upload was successful.

Comment: `:` is the issue in my case. After removing it from file name it's working as expected thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Something similar happened to me, the context was this: through the view I was loading a file through an input. When I tried to save the file to a folder, I got this error. I use laravel 9 with livewire.
In the end I just had to use the methods provided by liveware:

```
$filename = time() . $this->documento->getClientOriginalName();
$this->documento->storeAs('documents', $filename, 'public');
```

Fuentes: https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/file-uploads

Answer (score 0):

Ah damn, it seems as my filelengths were over 255 characters and thus the filesystem wasn't liking it. I've changed from Crypt to MD5 and the issue is now resolved.